# Calling javascript function upon returning whatever kind of result in controller action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bpopup

I'm stuck with the following scenario:

On my view there's a list of items. Depending on what the item represents, clicking on an item will take you to the appropriate view and display those results. Now displaying results in a view is not a problem; that is working fine. However, some items should be displayed in a popup and not in a view. I'm using a partial view together with bPopup and a javascript function like ShowListDialog(data) to show the dialog and bind the data. How do I call the javascript function upon returning whatever result needs be (I'm suspecting JavaScriptResult) in the action.

What I think my action should look like at the moment is:

public ActionResult ResponseItem(int reference)
{
    ResponseBase response = repository.RetrieveResponse(reference);

```
if (response.ShouldShowInView)
{
    return View(response.RedirectUrl, response.Data);
}
else
{
    return JavaScript("ShowListDialog(" + response.Data.JsonString + ");");
}
```

}

I have been looking at examples of return a JavaScript result and I can't even get that to work. If I say something like:

return JavaScript("alert('Hello');");

then in IE it asks me if I would like to open the javascript file; and in Chrome and Firefox it simply displays alert('Hello'); on the page.

Thanks in advance for help :)
D

Comment: Do you want to generate some javascript and execute it?  You can simple generate a html page which contains a <script></script> tag and put your script in it.

Comment: Nope, I want to call an existing javascript function called ShowListDialog that will display a popup dialog on top of the current page (if the clicked list item yields a response type that needs to be displayed in a popup). Displaying the view related items is no problem.

Comment: I see, what i meant was you can generate a html response, including a script tag, put your scripts ShowListDialog(...) in it. Then the scripts will be called.

Comment: It looks more like that you should return some status code to your client, and call ShowListDialog from javascript on the client side based on the status code.

Answer (score 0):

when looping through the items can you decide which is pop up and which isn't then link to 2 separate actions based on that?

JavaScriptResult only works if you call the action through ajax so that might be why it's not working (in case you aren't). you could prob use this to tell in action if it's an ajax request then return the appropriate result.